# Passing an element into a function that updates it later

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I am making a browser extension that adds a button next to each course listing on my university's course catalog that shows the student reviews of that course on a community forum.

I **scrape** the reviews from the forum and store the data on a Github repo. Then the extension gets the data from the repo and displays it on the screen.

In the following code, the loop adds a button `div` to each course. When it is clicked for the first time, it calls `getReviews()` to get the data on my Github repo. A new div called `reviews` is made to display the data. Now the course name and `reviews` is passed to `getReviews()`, which is supposed to get the data, and update `reviews` with the data acquired.

I tried to execute `getReviews()` in Firefox's console and it works as intended. All the alerts are shown, and the reviews are displayed correctly. But when I add the extension and click on the button, `getReviews()` does not correctly update the contents of `reviews`. The alerts inside `getReviews()` are not even shown.

What could be the cause of this issue?

```
var headers = document.getElementsByClassName("course");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    var courseinfo = headers[i].querySelector('.courseinfo');
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute('class', 'review_btn');
    let spn = document.createElement("span");
    spn.setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 12px; color: #f5425a; font-weight: bold;');
    spn.innerHTML = "[REVIEWS]"
    courseinfo.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(spn);
    let j = i;
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if ( headers[j].querySelector('.reviews') === null ) {
            var reviews = document.createElement('div');
            reviews.setAttribute('class', 'reviews');
            var course_name = headers[j].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML.substring(0,4).concat(headers[j].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML.substring(5,9));

            getReviews(course_name, reviews)
            reviews.innerHTML = "text";
            
            headers[j].insertBefore(reviews, headers[j].querySelector('.sections'));
        } else {
            if ( headers[j].querySelector('.reviews').style.display === "none" ) {
                headers[j].querySelector('.reviews').style.display = "block";
            } else {
                headers[j].querySelector('.reviews').style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    } );
}

function getReviews(course, elem){
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                alert(request.responseText);
                reply = JSON.parse(request.responseText)["content"];
                alert(reply);
                alert(atob(reply));
                div.innerHTML = atob(reply)
                return atob(reply);
        }
    }
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/my_name/review_tracker/contents/reviews/' + course + '.txt');
    request.send(null);
}
```